# How can I do to select all in a multi select using React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, multi-select

https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-wkpht

```
import React from 'react';
import chroma from 'chroma-js';

import { colourOptions } from './docs/data';
import Select from 'react-select';

const colourStyles = {
  control: styles => ({ ...styles, backgroundColor: 'white' }),
  option: (styles, { data, isDisabled, isFocused, isSelected }) => {
    const color = chroma(data.color);
    return {
      ...styles,
      backgroundColor: isDisabled
        ? null
        : isSelected
        ? data.color
        : isFocused
        ? color.alpha(0.1).css()
        : null,
      color: isDisabled
        ? '#ccc'
        : isSelected
        ? chroma.contrast(color, 'white') > 2
          ? 'white'
          : 'black'
        : data.color,
      cursor: isDisabled ? 'not-allowed' : 'default',

      ':active': {
        ...styles[':active'],
        backgroundColor: !isDisabled && (isSelected ? data.color : color.alpha(0.3).css()),
      },
    };
  },
  multiValue: (styles, { data }) => {
    const color = chroma(data.color);
    return {
      ...styles,
      backgroundColor: color.alpha(0.1).css(),
    };
  },
  multiValueLabel: (styles, { data }) => ({
    ...styles,
    color: data.color,
  }),
  multiValueRemove: (styles, { data }) => ({
    ...styles,
    color: data.color,
    ':hover': {
      backgroundColor: data.color,
      color: 'white',
    },
  }),
};

export default () => (
  <Select
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    defaultValue={[colourOptions[0], colourOptions[1]]}
    isMulti
    options={colourOptions}
    styles={colourStyles}
  />
);
```

I have this code using React.js and I would like to add 'all' and when I select all all the items in the select are selected.
How can I do to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an option to select all values and store the selected options in state. When 'all' option is selected, set all options in state and unset when unselect all is clicked.

Note: 'Select all' option and 'Unselect all' option must have the same value to perform the toggle operation.

I have updated your code which does these.
Refer: https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-3j7lf?file=/example.js